Android Studio not seeing my tables imported from models file
I've been writing a notes program for school and i've run into some issues while importing my database file. My MainData.java reads the .Models.Notes file but doesen't read all of the values/tables inside. I'll attach code of both of them.
Notes.Java file that I'm importing them from :
package com.example.noteappy.Models;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.io.Serializable;

    @Entity(tableName = "notes")
    public class Notes implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int ID = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    String title = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "notes")
    String notes = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    String date = "";

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pinned")
    boolean pinned = false;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public boolean isPinned() {
        return pinned;
    }

    public void setPinned(boolean pinned) {
        this.pinned = pinned;
    }
}



MainData.java file where the errors occur I've marked all error in bold, but basically it doesen't read tables for notes, id and title :
package com.example.noteappy.Database;
import com.example.noteappy.Models.Notes;

import static androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;



import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface MainData {
    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void insert(Notes notes);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM **notes** ORDER BY **id** DESC")
        List<Notes> getAll();

    @Query("UPDATE **notes ** SET **title** = :title, **notes** = :notes WHERE  **ID**  = :id ")
    void update(int id, String title, String notes);

    @Delete
    void delete(Notes notes);

}


If anything else needs to be attached that would help i'll gladly attach it.
side panel to see file tree
I've tried rewriting the code, Invalidating caches, repairing IDE, renaming everything, adding other imports, ALT + enter doesent work it just says "Unresolved refrence in Room SQL", looking at other forums. The error occured the first time i ran the app, the app opens in simulator but when i press a button it crashes.
